# How to differentiate between equally-named Prometheus metrics from dynamically discovered micro-services in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I’m looking for a way to differentiate between Prometheus metrics gathered from different dynamically discovered services running in a Kubernetes cluster (we’re using https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator). E.g. for the metrics written into the db, I would like to understand from which service they actually came.
I guess you can do this via a label from within the respective services, however, swagger-stats (http://swaggerstats.io/) which we’re using does not yet offer this functionality (to enhance this, there is an issue open: https://github.com/slanatech/swagger-stats/issues/50). 
Is there a way to implement this over Prometheus itself, e.g. that Prometheus adds a service-specific label per time series after a scrape?

Appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement this over Prometheus itself, e.g. that Prometheus adds a service-specific label per time series after a scrape?

This is how Prometheus is designed to be used, as a target doesn't know how the monitoring system views it and prefixing metric names makes cross-service analysis harder. Both setting labels across an entire target and prefixing metric names are considered anti-patterns.

What you want is called a target label, these usually come from relabelling applied to metadata from service discovery.

When using the Prometheus Operator, you can specify `targetLabels` as a list of labels to copy from the Kubernetes Service to the Prometheus targets.

Comment: Hi Brain, can you provide a link to documentation or example code.

Comment: These links might be helpful: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config   https://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus